# ArcGIS Online Print widget legend name displayed as "Override1" for polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-online

I am having an issue when printing maps where my polygon layers are displayed as "override 1", "override 2" etc, however line and point layers are displaying correctly. After investigating on Esri Community I discovered that this is an ongoing bug that appears to not have been fixed, see link for more info:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/arcgis-online-print-widget-pdf-legend-name/td-p/256270

I am wondering if anyone has come across this same issue, as it seems it would be a relatively common one for users of AGOL and their associated apps, and whether there is a work around of some kind. [image]